# Pandas to Polars .apply function

Tags: python, pandas, python-polars

In pandas I create an empty dataframe and populate each column using several .apply functions based on an input dataframe. Something like this:

```
def create_pin(c, county):
    if str(c['field']) == " ":
        pin = '{}-{}'.format(str(c['field1']), str(c['field2'])).replace(' 
        ','').replace('/','')
    else:
        pin = '{}-{}'.format(str(c['field']), str(c['field1'])).replace(' 
        ','').replace('/','') # we need to keep letters.
    pin_list = [letter_replacement[x.upper()] if x.isalpha() else x for x in pin]
    pin = ''.join(pin_list)

    return pin

out_df['PIN'] = in_df.apply(create_pin, axis=1, args=(county, ))
```

I am hoping to convert this logic to polars to try to speed up processing time. As of right now I have this and it works but I want to apply the function to a column in the output dataframe like I do in the pandas example. Here is the polars logic:

```
def create_pin(struct: dict) -> int:
    if str(struct['field']) == " ":
        pin = '{}-{}'.format(str(struct['field1']), str(struct['field2'])).replace(' 
        ','').replace('/','')
    else:
        pin = '{}-{}'.format(str(struct['field1']), str(struct['field'])).replace(' 
        ','').replace('/','') # we need to keep letters.
    pin_list = [letter_replacement[x.upper()] if x.isalpha() else x for x in pin]
    pin = ''.join(pin_list)

    return pin

in_df.with_columns([
                pl.struct(["field", "field1", 
"field2"]).map_elements(create_pin).alias("PIN")
])
```

Is it possible to do something like out_df['PIN'] = polars map_elements logic to create the PIN column in a dataframe. Then continue on and create several other columns in the out_df using similar logic.

Thanks in advance.
The input dataframe is the first image and the expceted output is the second. There are rows in the df that do not contain data for "field" so in those cases we want to use "field2" instead.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you provide an example input dataframe and the corresponding expected output?

Comment: I don't know what `letter_replacement` is but you can very likely convert the whole function to polars expressions. While you're at @Hericks's request, look into [`conditionals`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/user-guide/expressions/functions/#conditionals) and [`pl.format`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.format.html#polars.format). Just to reiterate, if you're hoping to speed up processing times, resorting to `map_elements` isn't going to help much. It bypasses all/most of polars's optimizations and speed when you use it.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor thanks for the idea, I'll give that a shot. Do you know if there is a way to populate the column in my empty dataframe with the conditional and pl.format functionality? Like you would access column "col" via df["col"] in pandas.

Comment: Probably but I don't want to assume anything about your input output so please give an example of input and what you want the output to look like.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor    I've added some screen shots, hopefully this helps clear things up.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor I think I have this figured out using conditionals and formatting for this example I think instead of populating empty columns like I do in pandas I'll just keep adding on the columns to the input df then delete the un-needed columns at the end. Does that sound like the correct workflow?

Comment: for transparacny sake here is the conditional i wrote for this example: in_df = in_df.select(
    pl.when(pl.col("field") == " ")
    .then(pl.format("{}-{}", pl.col("field1"), "field2"))
    .otherwise(pl.format("{}-{}", pl.col("field1"), "field"))
    .alias("PIN"),
    )

Comment: screenshots are frowned on as it requires people to transcribe things, instead, do something like `print(df.sample(5).select(columns).to_init_repr())` and post that. Don't *just* post that though. Please, also post what you'd expect the output to be. Make sure the example covers the different cases.

Comment: If you're able to figure it out on your own then please post it as an answer so people know the issue is resolved and so that others can reference it in the future.

Comment: For an example, you can just add a 2 row dataframe that displays both conditions so we can run your code, e.g. `df = pl.DataFrame({"field2": [1, 2], "field1": [3, 4], "field": [" ", "5"]})` and also the definition of `letter_replacement`. The else conditions in both examples differ, `'field', 'field1'` for pandas and  `'field1', 'field'` for polars. I'm guessing they should both be the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [conditionals](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/user-guide/expressions/functions/#count-unique-values) and [format](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.format.html#polars.format) I was able to achieve the desired output of a formatted string where data exists.

Example:

```
out_df = (
    in_df
    .select(
        pl.when(pl.col("field") == " ")
        .then(pl.format("{}-{}", pl.col("field1"), "field2"))
        .otherwise(pl.format("{}-{}", pl.col("field1"), "field"))
        .alias("PIN"),
))
```